# How to check connectivity to Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: c#, api, graph

Behind the problem:

I am using Microsoft Graph to receive some emails and store them in a database using SSMS and SQL Server. This is done once every day. I will have to delete the current data in the database and get the new fresh one from the Graph API.

But before I delete the data from my database, I will need to make sure that I am connected to Microsoft Graph.

An example of what I expect

[image: 1]

So the question(s) is: how do I check the connectivity to Microsoft Graph?

I have not tried anything special, but I expect to call a method that would return a true value if there is a connection and a error of some sort if there ain't a connection.

Comment: How do you call Graph API? Do you use Graph API C# SDK library? Do you use delegated or application permission type?

Comment: There is one real case that can happen in your scenario. You will check the connectivity to Graph API and it will succeed. Then you delete the data from DB. Then try to get fresh data from Graph API and it will fail (in meanwhile Graph API stop working for some reason).
I would do you the opposite. Call Graph API to get the fresh data. If the call succeed then delete the data in DB and replace them with the fresh one. If the call fails then do not delete data in DB try it later or something else.

Comment: Btw. there is no endpoint to check the connectivity of Graph API. If there is no connection the request will fail and you will receive status code 408, 500 or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclution that for Microsoft Graph, it would be best to do the following:

1: Call the API, and recieve data.

2: Check the recieved data and check if it alright.

3: Overrite the data in the DB.

Thank you for the comments, they helped me come to my solution.